Kafka Consumer Detaching from Topic Randomly in Spring Boot Service
I'm experiencing an issue with a Kafka consumer detaching randomly from a specific topic in my Spring Boot service. Here are the details:
Environment:

Kafka Cluster: 3 Brokers (on-prem), Kafka version 2.7.1
Kubernetes: Version 1.19
Spring Boot: Version 2.5.2
Spring Kafka Dependency: Version 2.8.1
Service Details:

Dockerized service running on Kubernetes, called notification-service.
The service is configured to consume messages from multiple Kafka topics with the same configuration (no dynamic configs).
Issue:
The consumer is randomly detaching from the topic telegram-notifications, while other topics are functioning correctly.
Topic Description:
./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server app-kafka1.xyz.com:9092 --describe --topic "telegram-notifications"

Topic: telegram-notifications
PartitionCount: 2
ReplicationFactor: 1
Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824

Topic: telegram-notifications    Partition: 0    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1    Isr: 1
Topic: telegram-notifications    Partition: 1    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2    Isr: 2

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have insights into why this consumer might be detaching only from this specific topic? Any help or suggestions for debugging would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Context:

No error logs related to this issue have been found in the service.
Other consumers on different topics remain attached and functional.
When I restarted the K8s deployment, it starts to read from the topic. (LAG decreases)

I tried restarting the Kubernetes deployment, and then the LAG on Kafka queue starts to decrease.

You can enable more detailed logging for the Kafka consumer in the Spring Boot service. You can increase the logging level for the Kafka consumer by adding the following configuration in your application.properties or application.yml file:
logging.level.org.springframework.kafka=DEBUG
and
logging.level.org.apache.kafka=DEBUG

Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029822/andrzej-sydor
